# Retrieve specific Classes from hierarchy

Tags: c#, reflection, hierarchy

The task of my programm is to simulate a car service station workflow. One of its part is a registration of incoming vehicle (it can be a car, truck or bus). Depending of vehicle type programm have to choose those parts of vehicle which can be repaired. 
For Car - Hull, Breaks, Wheels.
For Truck - same as for a Car AND Hydraulics.
For Bus - same as for a Car AND Interiror.

I've created next set of classes:

```
//vehicle types
public abstract class Vehicle {}

public class Car : Vehicle {}

public class Truck : Vehicle {}

public class Bus : Vehicle {}

//vehicle parts types
public abstract class VehiclePart
{

    public short State { get; set;}

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.GetType().Name; }
    }
}

public abstract class CarVehiclePart : VehiclePart { }

public abstract class TruckVehiclePart : VehiclePart { }

public abstract class BusVehiclePart : VehiclePart { }


public class Hull : CarVehiclePart { }

public class Wheels : CarVehiclePart { }

public class Breaks : CarVehiclePart { }

public class Hydraulics : TruckVehiclePart { }

public class Interior : BusVehiclePart { }

public class Handrail : BusVehiclePart { }
```

What I try to achieve is to get full list of classes, presents parts for each type of vehicle.
Can I do that with these classes or should I rewrite this huerarchy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look into c# generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend modelling the parts as an enum instead of classes. Also, you can use polymorphism with the method GetPartsToRepair. When the object is of type Car, the 3 parts that need to be repaired for every vehicle type is returned, if its of type Truck, it adds the Hydraulics and if its a Bus it adds the Interior.

It would be something like this:

```
public enum VehiclePart{
  Hull,
  Wheels,
  Breaks,
  Hydraulics,
  Interior,
  Handrail,
}

//vehicle types
public abstract class Vehicle {
    public virtual List<VehiclePart> GetPartsToRepair(){
        return new List<VehiclePart>(){ VehiclePart.Hull, VehiclePart.Wheels, VehiclePart.Breaks };
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle { }

public class Truck : Vehicle 
{
    public override List<VehiclePart> GetPartsToRepair(){
        var result = base.GetPartsToRepair();
        result.Add(VehiclePart.Hydraulics);
        return result;
    }
}

public class Bus : Vehicle 
{
    public override List<VehiclePart> GetPartsToRepair(){
        var result = base.GetPartsToRepair();
        result.Add(VehiclePart.Interior);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need in terms of extendability. Thanks!